# Can't install module Webform because more than 2MB

Tags: webforms, installation

I keep getting the error that the file exceeds 2MB and that that is the maximum allowed. This is when I try to upload it.

For now it only happens with the module Webform for drupal 8.
Is there any way I can compress this so that it is not too big?

Or how do I put it in manually if there is no other way?

Comment: Run `composer require drupal/webform` in the terminal. Make sure to run it in the web root directory.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me! I'm afraid I'll need more information about the terms you are using, because I'm a total noob at all of this.

Comment: Maybe easier to go to drupal.org/project/webform and download the zip file. Then extract that file and move it to your sites modules folder. Then go to admin > extend and enable the module.

Comment: What do you mean "try to upload it"? Are you using a 3rd party hosting solution?

Comment: @mbomb007 if your webhost has a File Manager, you can use that upload the webform module files to your webhost. Otherwise, you'll need a program like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) and connect to your webhost via SFTP to upload the files.

Comment: That's not necessarily how it works if you do the hosting yourself. For example, you could simply pull a repository.